# Is it OK to have single flag and use value -1 as 'disabled'?

Tags: design, design-patterns, coding-style

I have situation like this:

```
if (FLAG && number_of_kittens > FLAG_VALUE) {

}
```

The general logic of the application is that the `FLAG_VALUE` does not make sense to be negative.

My suggestion was to use `-1` to indicate is as disabled. My main motivation was to avoid confusion... But I have no data or empiral evidence to support my claim. What is the recommended practice in situations like this?

---

I hope I aimed right: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in

Comment: Why not set `FLAG` to MAXINT?

Comment: Maybe "FLAG" is not the best name for it, if it's storing numeric values? Usually a flag is a boolean, as an analog for a flag that is either up or down.

Comment: This is pretty heavily dependent on language

Comment: Use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), [`Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html), [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or similar thing depending on your language.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Toss Swift's [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional) and C#'s [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) in the mix

Comment: @Alexander I'm quite sure you can add a few to the mix. I'd left `Nullable<T>` out as it has slightly different behaviour (it's not composable with itself).

Answer (score 12):

This is generally a bad idea. It is called a sentinel value, and is discouraged in most languages, because it conflates two different concerns into a single value.

The problem is you can easily forget to check for the "magic" value, and the language will not help you since the two distinct cases are expressed as the same type. If you add "3 kittens" to "disabled" it will result in "2 kittens" which is deceptively wrong since it looks like a correct result. This is the worst kind of bug.

You should have number-of-kittens and FLAG in two different variables/fields. Or you could use an Option-type or a nullable int, depending on what the language provides.

Comment: While I agree that there's good reason to make it two variables, I have trouble believing that sentinel values are "discouraged in most languages" when `null`/`None`/`nil` appears in so many of them.

Comment: @CortAmmon: `null` appears in the language yes, but is not a value of an object. Instead, it is there instead of the object.

Comment: @MooingDuck How is that different from any other sentinel?  In both cases, it is a value of a variable which indicates that this variable's behavior is quite different from all other valid values for that variable.

Comment: @CortAmmon: The problem is when the sentinel value is of the same type as a regular value. -1 is a valid integer value and support the same operations as any other integer. null on the other hand does not support any of the same operations, so there is no risk of treating it as a regular value. (Null is not necessarily the best way of indicating a missing value, but it is certainly better than -1)

Comment: @JacquesB In what languages?  In python, C, C++, and Java (i.e. languages I know), if I have a variable which is a reference to a Duck, I can tell it `myReference.quack()`.  If that variable is null or None in those languages, the result compiles perfectly fine, and I only see issues at runtime: null pointer exception or undefined behavior.  If I remember, small-talk is even more insidious, where if I send the `quack` message to None, it silently accepts the message and does nothing.

Comment: @CortAmmon The reason null is better than -1 is at least you get an error if you try to use it like a normal value. If we do `print "You need at least ${FLAG_VALUE*2} kittens for bonus points!";` and FLAG_VALUE is -1, then we tell the user they need at least -2 kittens. If the sentinel value was null, you'd get an error which makes it blatantly obvious something went wrong (and is much easier to spot for that reason).

Comment: @immibis That is a language dependent argument.  There are languages for which it is true.  However, Smalltalk, as far as I know, silently ignores such errors.  C++ yields undefined behavior, which is terribly nefarious because it can do *anything*, including appear to work fine while corrupting unrelated data. I think your argument is strong for some languages such as Java, C#, and Python, which provide guarantees about how it will fail.  Even then, python has some funny behaviors with equality comparisons of custom classes and None.

Comment: I have programmed in C++ and I do not understand your code. Using "magic values" is not necessarily bad if it is obvious, this is not that obvious.

Comment: The broader term for this is "in-band signalling" which has an inherent danger. Control signals are inserted into the data stream which allows misinterpretation. There is a classic example about little Johnny demonstrating his new nose flute to granny over the phone. Whenever he blew the whistle, the connection would be terminated because he hit the magic frequency.

Comment: @CortAmmon: In Smalltalk `3 + Nil` yields an error like in Python. In C#, `3 + null` yields `null`. In any case you notice something is wrong, while `3 + -1` will yield 2 in any language which is deceptively wrong since it looks like a correct result. C++ does not have nullable int at all, AFAIK. (BTW i am not advocating null as sentinel value, often an Option-type is more appropriate, but null is at least much better than -1)

Answer (score 12):

This is a bad idea.

What if two shops merge: 1 shop has 8 kittens.
The other shop doesn't sell kittens.

Now they merge and you add all inventory together and suddenly find out the combined shop has 7 kittens.

So while it might look as easy solution now, for all time you should keep checking whether the flag is enabled or not and only after that you can do math on it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how you are using these variables, and I find that code confusing to read.

Easier to read & understand would be something like this:

```
bool kittens_enabled;
int number_of_kittens;
int min_num_kittens = 2; //2 is default.
//... stuff happens ...
if (kittens_enabled && number_of_kittens > min_num_kittens) {

}
```

I don't know if this captures the *meaning* of what you're trying to do, but the variable names make more sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, I've over-simplified stuff.... Now we have 5 lines of code LOL

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are severely constrained for memory, I strongly discourage using one variable to represent two things. If you were working for me, I would forbid it :)

If using two variables will be a problem, it's acceptable to use one variable to represent two things like you described.

Answer (score 3):

Well "-1" means disabled to you, but what about another coder 6 months down the road?  It becomes less appealing then.  If the language supports null-able types, this would be cleaner:

```
    const int numberOfKittens = 10;
    int? flag = null;

    if (flag.HasValue && numberOfKittens > flag.Value)
    {
        //DoSomething
    }
```

Then there is no magic -1 involved.

Comment: Or even better an Optional <Integer> as that draws attention to the optionalness (although looking at your code sample that may be what you're doing)

Comment: @RichardTingle: Basically. `int?` is the C# spelling of `Nullable<Int32>` -- a type that can represent every valid int value, or no value at all. Java's `Optional<Integer>` appears to have the same semantics, if slightly more FPish an API.